# PHP variable value from string

Tags: php, string, variables, eval

How can I get value from variable which is string ?

```
$Member_Student        = 3600;
$selectedItem = "Member_Student";
$price = "$" . $selectedItem;
print_r($price); //prints $Member_Student instead of 3600
```

I cannot use eval function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [curly braces to denote a variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

```
$Member_Student        = 3600;
$selectedItem = "Member_Student";
$price = ${$selectedItem};
print_r($price); // prints 3600
```

Answer (score 8):

use 2 $ signs:

```
var_dump($$selectedItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a variable from another variable containing its name use `print_r($$selectedItem );`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$selectedItem = "Member_Student";
```

to

```
$selectedItem = "$Member_Student";
```